# OWIN as audience for IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net, owin, identityserver4

My organization uses an IdentityServer4 for Bearer-Authentication as a Single-Sign-On Provider.

We also have a number of services written in .NET Framework 4.6 and OWIN. What would be the "correct" way to validate tokens from IdentityServer4 in an OWIN Web API?

I found the NuGet-Package IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation which works with OWIN. But the package IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation seems only to work with ASP.NET Core as far as I understand it.

Do I have to configure validation manually via the IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationMiddleware class? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use IdentityServer 3 packages for .NET Framework 4.6 applications while IdentityServer 4 runs on .net core.

They should be compatible and I know this is true for .net core 1.1. I haven't tried for .net core 2.0. There are lots of breaking changes, but I assume it is still possible.

From the updated [article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4) from Scott Brady:

> When we integrate a client application with IdentityServer, we are not
>   integrating to an implementation. Instead we are integrating using the
>   OpenID Connect or OAuth specifications. This means any application
>   that currently works with IdentityServer 3 will work with
>   IdentityServer 4.

As a side note: IdentityServer 3 isn't maintained [anymore](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/06/end-of-identityserver3-maintenance/). But this shouldn't matter for the current packages.

Comment: Thank you! That's why we use IdentityServer4 in the first place, because IS3 isn't maintained. But yes, the package from IS3 works for validation just fine